# Group Chat In Android

Tags: android, livechat

I wanna implement very efficient group chat in android. How can I do that? Please give me your best suggestions and also some step by step tutorial will help me in this.

I want to do peer to peer chat and also group chat. So Both type of implementations I wanna implement. Any SDK is available there? Or Any java lib are there?

Please give me your best suggestions.

Thanks,
Jay Patel

Comment: Valid question. Been wondering this myself.

Comment: Thanks dude, I have one solution. But I am not sure. Can we implemented it using push notification service using C2DM thats now GCM?

Comment: I made a sample chat group chat application, but all it does is check for updates on my server every two seconds. I needed it for a proof of concept one day, but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: ya that solution I may be very complicated.!! We need to do it very efficient. M I right?

Comment: The description of GCM actually sounds perfect. `This could be a lightweight message telling the Android application that there is new data to be fetched from the server (for instance, a movie uploaded by a friend), or it could be a message containing up to 4kb of payload data (so apps like instant messaging can consume the message directly).`

Comment: @EGHDK Yes We really need to go with GCM only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with checking out Google's own [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html). This lets you push messages to other devices. After that, you can google and see if you find any [examples](http://code.google.com/p/jchat4android/) or [tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360208/chatting-in-android) and you are good to go!

Comment: I guess GCM is the way to go, but it seems almost too easy. Heh. I'll have to look into this again. @Jai let me know how you make out on this quest.

Comment: @EGHDK That's how it is when Google does something. Black magic I suspect. ^^ GL to you both.

Comment: @EGHDK Exactly dude GCM will be the best way for us.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code of Android Chat SDK developed using [Applozic](https://www.applozic.com) backend server and Chat SDKS.
https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK

PS: I am from Applozic

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit form like this for making a persistent group:

private void setConfig(MultiUserChat multiUserChat) {
    try {

```
    Form form = multiUserChat.getConfigurationForm();
    Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();
    for (Iterator<FormField> fields = submitForm.getFields(); fields.hasNext();) {
        FormField field = (FormField) fields.next();
        if (!FormField.TYPE_HIDDEN.equals(field.getType()) && field.getVariable() != null) {
            submitForm.setDefaultAnswer(field.getVariable());
        }
    }
    submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_publicroom", true);
    submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
    multiUserChat.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}